# Should "just" come before or after the verb?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, word-order

Which one is grammatically correct?

1. I just have studied German.
2. I have just studied German.

Or if these two are wrong, what sentence can I use?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is unidiomatic (I wouldn't say it was ungrammatical, but I don't think any native speaker would put the adverb between the subject and the auxiliary like that).

The second one is a normal, idiomatic structure, but because of the particular verb it reads rather oddly. The problem is that in the construction *I have just ...*, the "just" usually has the meaning of "only a short time ago"; but that is inconsistent with a verb like "study", which refers to a process that usually lasts a long time.

So it would have to be interpreted as "just" meaning "only". This is a perfectly good interpretation, and makes sense; but I think that, because of the competing sense of *I have just ...*, most speakers would avoid this and say "I have only studied German".

However, with a suitable context it can sound normal. So

> What languages did you study at school? I just studied German.

is fine. In that context, the meaning of "just" = "a short time ago" will not occur to the hearer, and the required meaning of "just" = "only" will be undersaood.

Answer (score 0):

*Just* in this context can mean “only” or “only recently” (as in “I just ate” — meaning that I very recently ate, not that I ate but did nothing else), but let us assume you mean the first.

*Just* usually modifies the word it immediately precedes.  So

- “Just I have studied German.” — only I, of all the people in the discussion, have studied German.
- “I have studied just German.” — I have studied German, but no other language.
- “I have just studied German.” — I have studied German, but never done anything else with the language, such as speaking it in a German-speaking country

So what would “I just have studied German” mean?

Well, one thing it mean is the same as "I have just studied German”.  The “have” and the “studied” are both part of the same verb-phrase.

Or it could mean “I have studied German in the past, but am not studying it now.”

Or maybe something else.

Because it’s ambiguous, I think most careful speakers would avoid it.  If said casually, and without other clues from context, I would interpret it the same as “I have just studied”.